# populating a dataSet component with data from data source

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, dataset, report-viewer2012

I'm trying to create a report in my application. I've added a DataSet component to my application and I'm trying to query some data from DB and load it into that Data set to be used in my report.Here's what I'm doing (basically calling a function depending on previous parameter)

```
 Private Sub GrabReportData(ByVal RepNo As Integer)
    Conn.Open()
    Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim reportDataset As DataSet

    Dim sql As String = "SELECT FirstName, LastName from tblCustNotes"

    adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, Conn)
    adapter.Fill(reportDataset, "DataTable1") 
End Sub
```

[image]

I added a DataTable1 here but when I run this code I get this error....

> Value cannot be null.

However I know for a fact that I have data in there.

I'm hoping to be able to Populate the ReportDataSet component and use it as datasource for my reports. First time doing this, struggling a bit. I'm more of a MS Access person :/

EDIT:

Per @Plutonix did this...

Deleted ReportDataSet component

```
     Dim reportDataset As New DataSet

    Dim sql As String = "SELECT FirstName, LastName from tblCustNotes"

    Using adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, Conn)
        adapter.Fill(reportDataset, "DataTable1")
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataset.tables(0))
    End Using
```

Comment: `Dim reportDataset As DataSet` declares a dataset variable - it does not create it nor does it create any tables in it

Comment: @plutonix - i added a DataTable inside the ReportDataSet manually

Comment: @plutonix - I'm basically trying to load data inside the ReportDataSet so that I can use that for my reports

Comment: Same comment: `adapter.Fill(reportDataset, "DataTable1")` is throwing the exception (you didnt say where) because `reportDataset` is nothing/null.  You only declared it and did not create a `New` instance of a dataset

Comment: @plutonix - i see what I did wrong. Do I even need the DataTable1 inside the dataset or can i just run it off the dataset values - whatever is in there once I fill it with the results of my query. I've never done this before. Do I even need the component DataSet ?

Comment: Contrary to the name, a DataSet does not contain data - its basically a container for DataTables and some added functionality.  Its DataTables   which actually contain the data

Comment: You apparently already wizarded a strongly type DataSet named `ReportDataSet` which should have the query/code to fill it.  I am not sure why you are creating another one - they arent the same thing.